# I am not able to fix the mobile menu hamburger icon and home icon in same line alongwith the hover menu does not appear according to hamburger menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, nav, hamburger-menu

Actually when i go on a mobile screen, my hamburger icon and home icon they both dont align on the same line despite the display been set to flex and content is justified with 'space-between'. Also the close button (times icon(font awesome)) which should appear on the top while hover is on, on the hamburger menu doesn't appear. please if someone can help, as this thing is hindering my project.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button a").click(function(){
        $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);
       $(this).toggleClass('btn-open').toggleClass('btn-close');
    });
});
$('.overlay').on('click', function(){
    $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);   
    $(".button a").toggleClass('btn-open').toggleClass('btn-close');
    open = false;
});
```

```css
ol,
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}


a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*********************************
*** Marque
*********************************/
.marquee {
    background: #f2184f;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    /*border: 1px;
    border-left: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #FF5733 ;*/
}

.marquee a {
    color: #fafafa;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-weight: 400;
}

/*********************************
*** Logo Bar
*********************************/
#logo-bar {
    background: #ffffff;
    padding-top: 3px;
}

#logo-bar .logo {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

#logo-bar .logo img {
    max-width: 280px;
}

#logo-bar .logo-2 img {
    max-width: 200px;
    margin-left: 70px;
}

#menu {
    background: #202c45;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 3px -3px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#menu ul {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

#menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 20px;
}

#menu ul li:hover,
.active {
    background-color: orange;
    transition: ease-in .3s;
}

#menu ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#menu ul li:hover a {
    color: black;
    transition: ease-in .3s;
}

#menu ul li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    background: orange;
}

#menu ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 10px;
}

#menu ul li ul li {
    display: block;
}

#menu ul li ul li ul.nav-sub-sub-item {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    background: orange;
}

#menu ul li:hover ul li:hover ul.nav-sub-sub-item {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -35px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 10px;
}

#menu ul li ul li:hover {
    background: #2a4563;
    transition: ease-in .3s;
}

#menu ul li ul li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
    transition: ease-in .3s;
}


.mobile-menu {
    display: none;
}

/** Imported CSS outside media queries ****/
/** Imported CSS outside media queries ****/
/** Imported CSS outside media queries ****/
/** Imported CSS outside media queries ****/


nav {
    background: #202c45;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 3px -3px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    overflow: hidden;

}

nav .home {
    color: #fff;
}

nav ul {
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: #333;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1em 3em;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
    transition-property: all .2s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
    font-size: 16px;
}

nav ul li:hover {
    color: orange;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}

/*styling open close button*/

.btn-open:after {
    color: #fff;
    content: "\f0c9";
    font-family: "FontAwesome";

    transition-property: all .2s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
}

.btn-open:hover:after {
    color: #0066bf;
}

.btn-close:after {
    color: #0066bf;
    content: "\f00d";
    z-index:99;
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    transition-property: all .2s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
}

.btn-close:hover:after {
    color: #fff;
}

/* overlay */
.overlay {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    background: #f2184f;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 99;
}

.wrap {
    color: pink;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrap ul.wrap-nav {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575757;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    padding: 150px 0px 100px;
}

.wrap ul.wrap-nav li {
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 24%;
    position: relative;
}

.wrap ul.wrap-nav li a {
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition-property: all .2s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
}

.wrap ul.wrap-nav li a:hover {
    color: #f0f0f0;
    background: #202c45;
}

.wrap ul.wrap-nav ul {
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.wrap ul.wrap-nav ul li {
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #e9e9e9;
}

.wrap ul.wrap-nav ul li a {
    color: #f0f0f0;
}

.wrap ul.wrap-nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.social {
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.social p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 0 5px 0;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.social p a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.social-icon {
    width: 80px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #e9e9e9;
    color: #333;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 20px;
    transition-property: all .2s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
}

.social-icon:hover {
    background: #34B484;
    color: #f0f0f0;
}

.social-icon i {
    margin-top: 12px;
}


/** Imported CSS outside media queries ****/
/** Imported CSS outside media queries ****/
/** Imported CSS outside media queries ****/
/** Imported CSS outside media queries ****/
/** Imported CSS outside media queries ****/



@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    
    .marquee{
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .mobile-menu {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #logo-bar {
        display: none;
    }

    #menu {
        display: none;
    }

    


    /****** Imported Css *********/

    
    .wrap ul.wrap-nav>li {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 20px 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #575757;
    }

    .wrap ul.wrap-nav {
        padding: 30px 0px 0px;
    }

    nav ul {
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .social {
        color: #c1c1c1;
        font-size: 25px;
        padding: 15px 0;
    }

    .social-icon {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        background: #fff;
        color: #333;
        display: block;
        margin: 5px 0;
    }
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 200px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;






}



#title{
  min-height: 450px;
  background: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Home Style Sheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <!-- Font Awesome JavaScript -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Libre+Baskerville|Montserrat|Quicksand|Raleway|Slabo+27px&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Font Awesome JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0412137e5c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.js'></script>
    <script src='script/script.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>The Global University</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Header -->
    <!-- Marquee Starts -->
    <div class="marquee">
        <marquee behavior="scroll" scrollamount="4" direction="left" class="marqueeStyle" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
            <a href="https://www.theglobaluniversity.co.in" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-newspaper"></i> University will remain closed upto 30th May 2020 to avoid gathering &amp; prevention of spreading Novel Corona Virus </a>
        </marquee>
    </div>
    <!-- Marquee Ends-->
    <!-- Logo Bar Starts -->
    <header class="header">
        <div id="logo-bar">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="logo-bar">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="logo col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                            <a href="index.html">
                                <h1>Navbar LOGO</h1>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="logo-2 col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                            <h1>Second LOGO</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Student Login</button>&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Admin Login</button>
                            <h6><strong>Call Us:</strong> +91-234-234460</h6>
                            <h6><Strong>Email Us:</Strong></h6>
                            <h6>info@theexample.com</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mobile-menu">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="mobile-menu-1">
                    <h1>First Logo</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="mobile-menu-2">
                    <h6><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> +91-360-2277560/2142654554</h6>
                    <h6><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> info@theglobaluniversity.co.in</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
           
            <div class="mobile-navbar2">
                
<nav>
 
<div><a href="index.html"><i class="home fas fa-home"></i></a></div>
<div class="button"> 
  <a class="btn-open" href="#"></a>  
</div>

</nav>
<div class="overlay">
 <div class="wrap">
  <ul class="wrap-nav">
   <li><a href="#">About</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">About Company</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Designers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Developers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Pets</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Services</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.google.hr/">Web Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Development</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Apps</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Graphic design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Branding</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Work</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Web</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Graphic</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Apps</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="social">
   <a href="http://mario-loncarek.from.hr/">
   <div class="social-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
   </div>
   </a>
   <a href="#">
   <div class="social-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
   </div>
   </a>
   <a href="#">
   <div class="social-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-codepen"></i>
   </div>
   </a>
   <a href="#">
   <div class="social-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-behance"></i>
   </div>
   </a>
   <a href="#">
   <div class="social-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i>
   </div>
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

            </div>
            
        </div>
        <!-- Logo Bar Ends -->
        <!-- Menu Bar Starts -->
        <div id="menu">
            <div class="container">
                <ul>
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> </a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#!">About Us</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="about.html">About TGU</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="vision.html">TGU Vision</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="mission.html">TGU Mission</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="board.html">Message</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="#!">Approval</a>
                                <ul class="nav-sub-sub-item">
                                    <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="pdf/tgu-act.pdf" target="_blank">TGU Act</a></li>
                                    <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="pdf/UGC-consolidated-list.pdf" target="_blank">UGC List</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#!">Academic</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="department.html">Department</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="faculty.html">Faculty</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="syllabus.html">Syllabus</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#!">Admission</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="procedure.html">Procedure</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="applyonline.html">Apply Online</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="scholarship.html">Scholarship</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="download.html">Download Form</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="merit.html">Merit</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#!">Examination</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="pdf/exam_form.pdf" target="_blank">Exam Form</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="examnotice.html">Notice</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="admitcard.html">Admit Card</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="pdf/Verification_form.pdf" target="_blank">Verification</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#!">Research</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="phdadmissioncriteria.html">Admission Procedure</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="pdf/phd-mphil-application-form-min.pdf" target="_blank">Ph.D/M.Phil Entrance Form</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="pdf/ordinance-for-research-min.pdf" target="_blank">Ordinance For Research</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="pdf/Application-form-visiting faculty-min.pdf" target="_blank">Guide Application Form</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="pdf/consent-letter-from-guide-min.pdf" target="_blank">Guide Consent Form</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="pdf/progress-report-form-min.pdf" target="_blank">Progress Report Form</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="pdf/synopsis-format-min.pdf" target="_blank">Synopsis Format</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="pdf/course-work-syllabus-min.pdf" target="_blank">Syllabus of Coursework</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="pdf/scholar-assignment-min.pdf" target="_blank">Scholar Assignment</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="pdf/pre-phd-course-work-schedule-min.pdf" target="_blank">Pre Ph.D Course Work</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="pdf/thesis-format-min.pdf" target="_blank">Thesis Format</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="facilities.html">Facilities</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="facilities.html#library">Library</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="facilities.html#wifi-campus">WiFi Campus</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="facilities.html#hostel">Hostel & Cafe</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="facilities.html#digital">Digitalization</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="facilities.html#firstaid">First Aid</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="facilities.html#sports">Sports</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="search_button"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- Menu Bar Ends -->
    <!-- Title Starts -->
    <div id="title">
    </div>
```

Comment: I cannot find a close button element at all. Can you provide the selector to the element? It should appear after clicking on the hamburger icon, when seeing the menu, correct?

Comment: i have added both btn-open and btn-close in the css and added the button in the content

Answer (score 0):

I added the classes `button-home` and `button-menu` to the icons for more specific and explaining selectors.

```
<nav>
  <div class="button-home"><a href="index.html"><i class="home fas fa-home"></i></a></div>
  <div class="button button-menu">
    <a class="btn-open" href="#"></a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

To accomplish the requested position, you can use:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .button-home {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
  }
  .button-menu {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
  }
}
```

Your close button is not visible, because it's not part of the overlay and therefore the overlay is hiding it. I added it to the overlay:

```
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="wrap">
    <a class="btn-close" href="#"></a>
    <ul class="wrap-nav">
    ...
```

That way your class toggles are not necessary anymore, so I simplified your js and specified the btn-open selector a little bit more:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button-menu .btn-open").click(function() {
    $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);
  });
});
$('.overlay').on('click', function() {
  $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);
  open = false;
});
```

Now you only need to make your close button a little nicer.

Here is the full code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button-menu .btn-open").click(function() {
    $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);
  });
});
$('.overlay').on('click', function() {
  $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);
  open = false;
});
```

```css
ol,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*********************************
*** Marque
*********************************/

.marquee {
  background: #f2184f;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  /*border: 1px;
    border-left: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #FF5733 ;*/
}

.marquee a {
  color: #fafafa;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 400;
}


/*********************************
*** Logo Bar
*********************************/

#logo-bar {
  background: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 3px;
}

#logo-bar .logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#logo-bar .logo img {
  max-width: 280px;
}

#logo-bar .logo-2 img {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin-left: 70px;
}

#menu {
  background: #202c45;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 3px -3px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

#menu ul {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 20px;
}

#menu ul li:hover,
.active {
  background-color: orange;
  transition: ease-in .3s;
}

#menu ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#menu ul li:hover a {
  color: black;
  transition: ease-in .3s;
}

#menu ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  background: orange;
}

#menu ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}

#menu ul li ul li {
  display: block;
}

#menu ul li ul li ul.nav-sub-sub-item {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  background: orange;
}

#menu ul li:hover ul li:hover ul.nav-sub-sub-item {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -35px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}

#menu ul li ul li:hover {
  background: #2a4563;
  transition: ease-in .3s;
}

#menu ul li ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
  transition: ease-in .3s;
}

.mobile-menu {
  display: none;
}


/** Imported CSS outside media queries ****/


/** Imported CSS outside media queries ****/


/** Imported CSS outside media queries ****/


/** Imported CSS outside media queries ****/

nav {
  background: #202c45;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 3px -3px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav .home {
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul {
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #333;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 3em;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  transition-property: all .2s linear 0s;
  -moz-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
  font-size: 16px;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  color: orange;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}


/*styling open close button*/

.btn-open:after {
  color: #fff;
  content: "\f0c9";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  transition-property: all .2s linear 0s;
  -moz-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
}

.btn-open:hover:after {
  color: #0066bf;
}

.btn-close:after {
  color: #0066bf;
  content: "\f00d";
  z-index: 99;
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  transition-property: all .2s linear 0s;
  -moz-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
}

.btn-close:hover:after {
  color: #fff;
}


/* overlay */

.overlay {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f2184f;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 99;
}

.wrap {
  color: pink;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrap ul.wrap-nav {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #575757;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  padding: 150px 0px 100px;
}

.wrap ul.wrap-nav li {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 24%;
  position: relative;
}

.wrap ul.wrap-nav li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-property: all .2s linear 0s;
  -moz-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
}

.wrap ul.wrap-nav li a:hover {
  color: #f0f0f0;
  background: #202c45;
}

.wrap ul.wrap-nav ul {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.wrap ul.wrap-nav ul li {
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #e9e9e9;
}

.wrap ul.wrap-nav ul li a {
  color: #f0f0f0;
}

.wrap ul.wrap-nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.social {
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.social p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 0 5px 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.social p a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.social-icon {
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #e9e9e9;
  color: #333;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;
  transition-property: all .2s linear 0s;
  -moz-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
}

.social-icon:hover {
  background: #34B484;
  color: #f0f0f0;
}

.social-icon i {
  margin-top: 12px;
}


/** Imported CSS outside media queries ****/


/** Imported CSS outside media queries ****/


/** Imported CSS outside media queries ****/


/** Imported CSS outside media queries ****/


/** Imported CSS outside media queries ****/

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .marquee {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .mobile-menu {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #logo-bar {
    display: none;
  }
  #menu {
    display: none;
  }
  /****** Imported Css *********/
  .wrap ul.wrap-nav>li {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575757;
  }
  .wrap ul.wrap-nav {
    padding: 30px 0px 0px;
  }
  nav ul {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .social {
    color: #c1c1c1;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 15px 0;
  }
  .social-icon {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 0;
  }
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 200px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
}

#title {
  min-height: 450px;
  background: #eaeaea;
}


/* MODIFICATIONS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .button-home {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
  }
  .button-menu {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Home Style Sheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <!-- Font Awesome JavaScript -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Libre+Baskerville|Montserrat|Quicksand|Raleway|Slabo+27px&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Font Awesome JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0412137e5c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.js'></script>
  <script src='script/script.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
  <title>The Global University</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Header -->
  <!-- Marquee Starts -->
  <div class="marquee">
    <marquee behavior="scroll" scrollamount="4" direction="left" class="marqueeStyle" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
      <a href="https://www.theglobaluniversity.co.in" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-newspaper"></i> University will remain closed upto 30th May 2020 to avoid gathering &amp; prevention of spreading Novel Corona Virus </a>
    </marquee>
  </div>
  <!-- Marquee Ends-->
  <!-- Logo Bar Starts -->
  <header class="header">
    <div id="logo-bar">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="logo-bar">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="logo col-lg-6 col-md-6">
              <a href="index.html">
                <h1>Navbar LOGO</h1>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="logo-2 col-lg-3 col-md-3">
              <h1>Second LOGO</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
              <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Student Login</button>&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Admin Login</button>
              <h6><strong>Call Us:</strong> +91-234-234460</h6>
              <h6>
                <Strong>Email Us:</Strong>
              </h6>
              <h6>info@theexample.com</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mobile-menu">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="mobile-menu-1">
          <h1>First Logo</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="mobile-menu-2">
          <h6><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> +91-360-2277560/2142654554</h6>
          <h6><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> info@theglobaluniversity.co.in</h6>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="mobile-navbar2">

        <nav>

          <div class="button-home"><a href="index.html"><i class="home fas fa-home"></i></a></div>
          <div class="button button-menu">
            <a class="btn-open" href="#"></a>
          </div>

        </nav>
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="wrap">
            <a class="btn-close" href="#"></a>
            <ul class="wrap-nav">
              <li><a href="#">About</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">About Company</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Designers</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Developers</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Pets</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Services</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="https://www.google.hr/">Web Design</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Development</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Apps</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Graphic design</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Branding</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Work</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Web</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Graphic</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Apps</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="social">
              <a href="http://mario-loncarek.from.hr/">
                <div class="social-icon">
                  <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                </div>
              </a>
              <a href="#">
                <div class="social-icon">
                  <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                </div>
              </a>
              <a href="#">
                <div class="social-icon">
                  <i class="fa fa-codepen"></i>
                </div>
              </a>
              <a href="#">
                <div class="social-icon">
                  <i class="fa fa-behance"></i>
                </div>
              </a>
              <a href="#">
                <div class="social-icon">
                  <i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- Logo Bar Ends -->
    <!-- Menu Bar Starts -->
    <div id="menu">
      <div class="container">
        <ul>
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> </a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#!">About Us</a>
            <ul>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="about.html">About TGU</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="vision.html">TGU Vision</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="mission.html">TGU Mission</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="board.html">Message</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="#!">Approval</a>
                <ul class="nav-sub-sub-item">
                  <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="pdf/tgu-act.pdf" target="_blank">TGU Act</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="pdf/UGC-consolidated-list.pdf" target="_blank">UGC List</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#!">Academic</a>
            <ul>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="department.html">Department</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="faculty.html">Faculty</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="syllabus.html">Syllabus</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#!">Admission</a>
            <ul>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="procedure.html">Procedure</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="applyonline.html">Apply Online</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="scholarship.html">Scholarship</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="download.html">Download Form</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="merit.html">Merit</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#!">Examination</a>
            <ul>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="pdf/exam_form.pdf" target="_blank">Exam Form</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="examnotice.html">Notice</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="admitcard.html">Admit Card</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="pdf/Verification_form.pdf" target="_blank">Verification</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#!">Research</a>
            <ul>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="phdadmissioncriteria.html">Admission Procedure</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="pdf/phd-mphil-application-form-min.pdf" target="_blank">Ph.D/M.Phil Entrance Form</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="pdf/ordinance-for-research-min.pdf" target="_blank">Ordinance For Research</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="pdf/Application-form-visiting faculty-min.pdf" target="_blank">Guide Application Form</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="pdf/consent-letter-from-guide-min.pdf" target="_blank">Guide Consent Form</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="pdf/progress-report-form-min.pdf" target="_blank">Progress Report Form</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="pdf/synopsis-format-min.pdf" target="_blank">Synopsis Format</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="pdf/course-work-syllabus-min.pdf" target="_blank">Syllabus of Coursework</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="pdf/scholar-assignment-min.pdf" target="_blank">Scholar Assignment</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="pdf/pre-phd-course-work-schedule-min.pdf" target="_blank">Pre Ph.D Course Work</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="pdf/thesis-format-min.pdf" target="_blank">Thesis Format</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="facilities.html">Facilities</a>
            <ul>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="facilities.html#library">Library</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="facilities.html#wifi-campus">WiFi Campus</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="facilities.html#hostel">Hostel & Cafe</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="facilities.html#digital">Digitalization</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="facilities.html#firstaid">First Aid</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="facilities.html#sports">Sports</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          <li>
            <div class="search_button"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!-- Menu Bar Ends -->
  <!-- Title Starts -->
  <div id="title">
  </div>
```

Comment: i did this but i want it separated one from other like both at other end

Comment: @Shahrukh Check my new and now full solution.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i got lost with this pandemic. anyway it worked.